# Loop through attributes using DOM methods?

Tags: javascript

I need to remove some attributes and preserve some from a list of nodes. For instance, there is a list of `img` elements and you just need `src` and `alt` attributes, is there any way to loop through attributes of elements in a given list?

```
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class1">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class2">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class3">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class4">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class5">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class6">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class7">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class8">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class9">
 <img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="class10"> 

 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
```

Comment: Is the provided code the two parts i.e. the first block what exists and the second the desired result? Perhaps the first block is the "given list". Using element id's could be advantageous (e.g. if these were in a DIV) then you could get the DIV element and loop through the child nodes. e.g. `c = document.getElementById(AC_ChildDiv);
  for (i=0;i<c.childNodes.length;i++) {
   cp = c.childNodes[i];
   if (cp.className == AC_EOTCBase) {
    continue
   }`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Provide other details to [make this a better question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):  List what you've tried, research this on the internet, and tell us while the obvious solutions don't work. A quick Google search would turn up the [jquery .removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method, which seems perfect for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the attributes for each element, check the name of the attribute agains a white-list, and remove anything else using `removeAttribute()`

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for ( var i = images.length; i--; ) {
    for ( var j = images[i].attributes.length; j--; ) {

        var attribute = images[i].attributes[j]; 

        if ( ['src', 'alt'].indexOf( attribute.name ) === -1 ) {
            images[i].removeAttribute(attribute.name);
        }

    }
}
```